# Media query div not changing width but everything else works

Tags: html, css, width, media-queries

I am trying to adjust the width of a div when the browser decreases in size using max-width. The div does everything but change width. I have looked at it through the developer tools on the chrome browser and the width is slashed out. What's wrong?

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 500px)" href="responsive.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="left">
    </div>

    <div class="containerRight">
        <div class="incontainer">
            <div class="post"> Aifjoisdjfiosjdfoisdjfoidsjfoisjd</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**MAIN CSS:**

```
*{
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
box-sizing:border-box; 
}

html, body {
height:100%;
} 

body {
padding:60px 0 0 0; /* 60 — header height*/
margin:0;
}


.main {
min-width:100%;
height:60px;
margin-top: -60px;  /* 60 — header height*/
margin-left: -300px;
border-bottom: solid 1pt #ADADAD;
}


.containerRight {
float:left;
width:100%;
height: 100%;
overflow-y: scroll;
}



.left {
float:left;
height: 100%;
width: 300px;
border-right: solid 1px #C9C9C9;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0 2px #888888;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 0 2px #888888;
box-shadow: 1px 0 2px #888888;
}
```

**RESPONSIVE CSS**

```
.left {
   width: 800px;
   background-color: red;
}

.containerRight {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: What's your media query?

Comment: media=screen I am just testing it by changing the size of the browser. I am sorry if I did not answer your question. I don't know exactly what you mean by that.

Comment: @user3173447 your question says media query div not changing width but yet in your description, there is no media query at all

Comment: I assume that the main css is in a file other than responsive.css (theres no mention of it in the HTML)? If so, are you including main.css after responsive.css?

Comment: It's in the `<head>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of putting the `media=screen` in the head, for your responsive.css file, use this:

```
@media (max-width:500px){
    .left {
       width: 800px;
       background-color: red;
    }

    .containerRight {
       display: none;
    }
```

}

Learn the basics about media queries here: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-in-3-steps and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries. This should help you get started.

Comment: It should work in the `<head>` as you can see on the first example on the Moz-Dev link. I think it should be `min-width` rather than max, though it's hard to tell without the full code

Comment: @Xareyo you are absolutely correct and it should. It's a personal preference of using it in the CSS as I find it more reliable.

Comment: I think the crux of the matter here is where exactly is **main css** being included?

Comment: @Newtt Unfortunately the question makes it unclear where the **main css** is; is it in responsive.css? In its own file main.css (not shown in the HTML)? My inclination is that it's in main.css and the file is included after responsive.css - `.left` has the same specificity which would explain why `background-color` works (only exists in responsive) but `width` does not.

Comment: @Newtt Just to add, if it turns out that all the CSS is in responsive.css then your answer would be right on the button! ;)

Comment: @HiddenHobbes Hopefully that's the case. OP doesn't seem to be responding. :P

Comment: Yes that is why I had to ask in this forum because I was not able to get the width to adjust while everything else would. I followed what Newtt said and it worked perfectly. I tried to check mark it, but it was saying my thread was deleted.